# Wi-Fi problem on Acer Aspire One D257 running Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, acer, aspire

I finally installed 12.04 on my Acer Aspire One D257 today but the Wi-Fi keeps dropping. I turned it on, typed the password but the "**cannot connect**" message kept popping up. As I'm a novice of Ubuntu, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and all I did was update the driver for my wifi. Go to system setting then additional drivers, it should search for the driver needed and you should install/update it. Then go to the wifi settings in the top right corner and set up your wifi details and password in the same as you would using windows. I hope this helps, I am new to Ubuntu too, so good luck luck! :)